# Throwing but not catching

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to perform Firebase Phone authentication (Using SMS), using the flutter-fire package, but I'm running into some roadblocks when checking for error conditions during the "Verify" process.

One note : The throwing happens in a ChangeNotifierProvider and catching happens in a separate widget that is using the provider for state data.

When I try to debug, I see that the error is thrown, but the catch block doesn't get called.

This is where the error is thrown (PhoneVerificationFailed function):

`

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    print("Verify Phone Number called");
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
      this._verificationID = verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this._verificationID = verId;
      print("SMS Sent");
      this.smsSent = true;
      notifyListeners();
      throw (HttpException("Test"));
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationSuccessful =
        (AuthCredential user) {
      print("verified");
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException exception) {
      print("failed, ${exception.message}");
      throw (exception);
    };

    this._phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    notifyListeners();

    var result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
      codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 0),
      verificationCompleted: verificationSuccessful,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    );

    return result;
  }`
```

This is where I have the catch code:

```
`Future<void> _submitPhoneNumber() async {
    _formKey2.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
          .verifyPhoneNumber(_authData['phoneNo']);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print("Exception caught ${error.message}");
      errorSnackBar(error.message, "Close");
    }
  }
```

`

Edit : I'm playing around with the code playground in https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#example-async-and-await-with-try-catch and I see that the exception gets caught only if the Future returns something, even if the return type is Future. Could this be the root cause?

Comment: Do you found answer? I have similar problem now(

Answer (score 0):

You need the catch the exception that you are throwing.

```
 try {
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
          .verifyPhoneNumber(_authData['phoneNo']);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
  } on HttpException catch (e) {   // add on HttpException 
      print("Exception caught ${error.message}");
      errorSnackBar(error.message, "Close");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I thought the catch was a net to catch all exceptions? Anyway, I tried this and I didn't see a difference in behavior. Does it have anything to do with the throw and the catch being in 2 different files?

Comment: It can catch-all for that then -  just `throw('some error')`  not `HttpException`. @vybhavr

Comment: I am doing that: `final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException exception) {
      print("failed, ${exception.message}");
      throw (exception);
    };`

Comment: I'm playing around with the code playground in https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#example-async-and-await-with-try-catch and I see that the exception gets caught only if the Future returns something, even if the return type is Future. Could this be the root cause?

Comment: Ok. I'll try that, I'm running it another error now though. The statement after the "Await" isn't waiting for the async task to finish.This is in an async function.

`await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
      codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 0),
      verificationCompleted: verificationSuccessful,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    );

    print("Future error return called");
    return Future.error(AuthErrorException);`